# Is a Greasemonkey script that uses unsafeWindow secure as long as the @grant type is 'none'?

Tags: javascript, security, greasemonkey, code-injection

I've written a small Greasemonkey script to add a couple of hotkeys to YouTube for controlling the volume when the video doesn't necessarily have focus:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Custom Youtube Hotkeys
// @version  1
// @include  https://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var customScript_Player = unsafeWindow.document.getElementById("movie_player");

window.onkeypress = function(event) {
  //ignore keypress if focused on search bar
  if (unsafeWindow.document.activeElement.tagName === "INPUT") { return; }
  try {
    if (event.keyCode == 120) {
      customScript_Player.setVolume(customScript_Player.getVolume() + 5);
    } else if (event.keyCode == 122) {
      customScript_Player.setVolume(customScript_Player.getVolume() - 5);
    }
  } catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
};
```

However, I'm concerned about the security concerns raised with the use of unsafeWindow.
As far as I can tell, it's necessary to execute JavaScript on the page elements, but I'm seeing conflicting information about what security risks it poses.

I've seen a couple of discussions where it's claimed that the only security holes opened by its use come from the APIs Greasemonkey provides which are blocked using @grant    none in the script header, and that as long as grant is set to none the page can't do anything it wouldn't be able to normally.

However, the wiki itself makes several warnings about avoiding unsafeWindow and doesn't seem to ever specify its only a problem when using its own API.

Is the above script secure? If not, is there a safer way to inject javascript that can control the page elements?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You don't need unsafeWindow to access document. 2) In `@grant none` your script is already running in the context of unsafeWindow so it's redundant. 3) Use addEventListener with `keydown` instead of `onkeypress`.

Comment: Using:

var customScript_Player = document.getElementById("movie_player");
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  try { customScript_Player.setVolume(0); }
  catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
}, true);

I get "customScript_Player.setVolume is not a function" when pressing the hotkey. However, if I include unsafeWindow in the assignment to customScript_Player, it works fine, so there does seem to be some behavioral difference at least

Comment: Incidentally if I log the variable itself inside the event's callback, in the console the variable looks to be properly defined and includes the setVolume function, it just doesn't seem to be able to recognise it otherwise.

Comment: 1) unsafeWindow is necessary to access the page variables and functions like setVolume, indeed, but there's a safer alternative: wrappedJSObject instead of unsafeWindow 2) The devtools console runs in the original page context, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm concerned about the security concerns raised with the use of unsafeWindow.

In GreaseMonkey, userscripts run in `content` script context while webpage JavaScript runs in `page` context.

The [Xray vision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision) separation is made specially to prevent page JavaScript gaining access to privileged functions.

`unsafeWindow` creates a bridge between the 2 contexts which if not careful, can expose some of the `content` context functions to the `page` JavaScript.

**Note:** In GreaseMokey (& FireMonkey) `unsafeWindow` is an alias for `window.wrappedJSObject`. Therefore, there is no difference between using either.
TamperMonkey & ViolnetMonkey implementation of `unsafeWindow` is different.

In your example code, if you don't need to use any of the GM functions, you can simply inject the whole code into the `page` context without the need for `unsafeWindow` e.g.

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = '...code....';
document.body.appendChild(script);
script.remove(); // if you want, makes no difference
```